# Echarts: How to customize shadow area on datazoom

Tags: echarts

Any one know how to customize the blue shadow area highlighted in the following screenshot. I am using the latest 5.2.2 version.

Here is a official example page https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=bar-large

[image: how to change the blue area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 5.4 it's done by `dataZoom.moveHandleStyle` and `dataZoom.emphasis.moveHandleStyle` like this:

```
dataZoom: [
  {
    moveHandleStyle: {
      color: "red"
    },
    emphasis: {
      moveHandleStyle: {
        color: "orange"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-datazoom-handle-colors-mintrd?file=/index.js) a working codesandbox example

Documentation for [normal](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.moveHandleStyle) handle, [emphasised](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.emphasis.moveHandleStyle) one